# Firefox title bar and tabs merge

Tags: firefox, user-interface, web-browser, internet-browser

Since firefox update to 57 none of hide titlebar addons work. 
Is there a way to merge title bar with tabs, so that lines in picture provided belove becomes one?
[image: firefox title bar merge]

I tried merging with firefox settings, but somewhy it doesn't work.
Also I have tried using maximus, but that didn't work for me either.

Comment: Maybe the add-ons are not update yet for the new version of Firefox, you will need to wait to be updated. This is not a elementary os problem, I am almost sure of that

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully this will fix it overtime with version 59 of Firefox.
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/11/firefox-nightly-adds-csd-option

**Update:** In the latest update of Firefox (Quantum 60.0), this is now working! Just do this

1. Open Menu
2. Customize
3. Untick *Title Bar*

Answer (score 2):

The people behind Firefox seem to be working hard on client-side decoration, which will enable this feature without any extensions. Almost every day people are working out smaller and smaller issues. You could follow the following bug to keep up to date:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283299

Current nightly (60.0a1 (2018-02-21)):
[image]